# Strange UISCrollView behavior after Splash Screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, splash-screen

something strange is happening with one UISCrollview.

The scheme I have is  MainView -> ScrollView -> ViewScrollView

In

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if (appDelegate.first_time ) {
        NSLog(@"First time.We need to feed sqlite.");

        [self showSplash];

        appDelegate.first_time = false;
    }

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768*2, 870);
    [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    ... other stuff
}
```

The aplication loads and the scrollview works perfectly. **No issues at all.**

The unique problem I've is the first time that the app runs.
It needs to download some huge files to feed ipad's sqlite database, it can be pretty slow, (it has to download about 10Mb) so I've created an splash screen that shows how long it will take, how much has downloaded,etc...

as shown in the code I load it as [self showSplash];

```
#pragma mark splash screen
- (void)showSplash {

    NSLog(@"showSplash");

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    modalSplashScreenViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modalSplashScreenViewController"];
    sfvc.delegate = (id)self;
    [sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

It shows the splashScreen as should and starts downloading

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.dimBackground = YES;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";
    hud.detailsLabelText = @"updating data";
    hud.delegate = self;

    [hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(feed_it) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
- (void)feed_it{
    // feeds sqlite
    // when has finished closes the view.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After hiding the splash screen the UIScrollView doesn't scroll.

This is the log file I got from the end of "ViewDidAppear" which is called after the splashScreen closes. 
(Is EXACTLY the same if I run the app the second time that the splash screen doesnt appear)

```
_viewScrollView frame width  1536.000000 frame origin.x 0.000000
_viewScrollView frame height 870.000000 frame origin.y 0.000000
_scrollview frame width  768.000000 frame origin.x 0.000000
_scrollview frame height 870.000000 frame origin.y 45.000000
_scrollView.contentSize.width 1536.000000 height:870.000000
_scrollView.contentOffset.x 0.000000 y:0.000000
_scrollView.bounds.size.width 768.000000 height 870.000000 
_scrollView.intrinsicContentSize.width -1.000000
_scrollView.contentSize.width 1536.000000 height:870.000000
```

Without loading the splashscreen it works, and after loading it, doesnt.

Anyone has a clue what is going on?

Comment: Do other touch events respond, just not scrolling?

Comment: Can you show where you define the property for sfvc.delegate?

Comment: And finally, have you verified the MBProgressHUD is removed successfully?  (I think it blocks touch events.)

Comment: touch events responds I've tried to instead of showing this complex splash screen show just an empty view, and dismiss it after 1 sec. And I have exactly the same issue. So AFAIK MDProgressHUD is not involved. Maybe, Am I not showing the Splash Screen in a correct way? Another thing Ive tested, is to instead of load splashscreen in ViewDidApper load it in a button. Before I press the button scrollview works, after showing / hiding splashscreen it doesnt work.... really odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved it. This is the most weird thing I've ever seen in XCode.

I have plenty of modal views in this app using storyboard segues, and when I return back to the main view, scrollview works perfectly, so I've tried to show the splashscreen with a segue instead of coding it, and, MAGIC! It worked!

Deep looking at the code, the unique difference that I've found between

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    modalSplashScreenViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modalSplashScreenViewController"];
    sfvc.delegate = (id)self;
    [sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and the segue method was: the modalPresentationStyle,

on the IDE I had chosen "Page Sheet" and in the code way I had UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

So reverting all the code to the moment that I did the question here, and changing

```
[sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

for

```
[sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
```

scrollview works perfectly again.

Can anyone explain me why is this happening? Maybe a bug?